# CSS - How to make the width change of a div go left instead of right?

Tags: css, width, direction

So right now I have this little thing :

```css
table {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
    }
.arrow {
        border-radius: 1rem;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        transition: 200ms;
    }
    .arrow:hover {
        border-radius: 1.2rem;
        width: 120%;
        height: 120%;
    }
    .arrow:active {
        border-radius: 0.9rem;
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
        <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The div on the right is doing exaclty what I want, but I wish the one on the left would change width in the opposite direction. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: set direction for it's parent or itself.    direction:rtl;

Answer (score 1):

### Use `transform` instead of `width` and `height` for animation

Because `width` and `height` can cause content repaint and result in performance issues (e.g. if your layout consists of 100 containers and the 10 containers in the top changes their sizes, all 90 containers below will have to reflow and animate 60 times per second), it's typically recommended you use `transform` property when animating a resize. See [this Web.dev demo](https://web.dev/animations-guide/#resize)

### Use `transform-origin` to determine the transformation anchor point.

According to [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin):

> The transform origin is the point around which a transformation is applied. For example, the transform origin of the rotate() function is the center of rotation.

See the working code snippet below. I replaced your `width` and `height` lines with `transform: scale()`, and added a `transform-origin` distinction to each box.

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.arrow {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}

.left {
  transform-origin: right;
}

.right {
  transform-origin: left;
}

.arrow:hover {
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.arrow:active {
  border-radius: 0.9rem;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="arrow left"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="arrow right"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```